# How to select a dynamic range based on a cell value in Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am having a hard time trying to find anything relating to my question. All I have found so far is selecting ranges based off of a static range, but unfortunately the data can change from week to week.

There are multiple data blocks with different rows and columns located in the same sheet but have titles above the data. My goal is to find a title i.e. row 36 or 40, move a row down and essentially do a ctrl+down ctrl+right for selecting a range and then creating a table and naming a table based off of the title.[image: Report Example]

```
import openpyxl

def tables(title):
    for cell in pws_sheet["A"]: #pws_sheet["A"] will return all cells on the A column until the last one
        if (cell.value is not None): #check if cell is not empty
            if title in cell.value: #check if the value of the cell contains the title
                row_coord = cell.row #put row number into a variable

tables("All Call Distribution by Hour")
```

I'm currently able to find the row based off of the title, save the title into a variable, but I am lost on figuring out how to select the bottom right of each data block and selecting it as a range and creating the table from that range.

**EDIT 1:** Title row is correct, end row is the acting like `max_row`, and the `num_cols` is showing the cell.values instead of just a single max column for that table.

```
def find_table(title, sheet):
    title_row = None
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        if row[0].value == title:
            #Find the title row
            title_row = row[0].row
        if row[0].value is None and title_row:
            end_row = row[0].row - 1
            num_cols = [cell.value for cell in sheet[title_row+1] if cell.value is not None]
    else:
        #The last row in the sheet
        end_row = row[0].row
    print(f"Row: {title_row}, Column: {num_cols}, End Row: {end_row}")
    return title_row, num_cols, end_row
```

OUTPUTS: `Row: 40, Column: ['Within', '# Calls', '% Calls'], End Row: 138`

Comment: I have tried a variation of max_row and max_column, but max_column gives the furthest column regardless of what data block I'm in.

Comment: Have you tried detecting an empty cell/row/column to determine the limits of the table?

Comment: Unfortunately those are used cells in the sense something was removed from them. So I am not quite sure how to go about inserting that into the loop. Ideally since everything can be found in column "A" I could just search for the: Title, find blank row, select from row below title to above blank row, create the table. At this point though I would just like to be able to select the row below title to blank row and call it good. I've been on this for a week now, but everything I find is related to static ranges.

Comment: Ideally it would be ```Loop until BLANK cell, select row below title(top-left cell) and max_column(bot-right cell), create table```

Comment: One tactic that might help (or might even be _required_ to enable you to solve the problem) would be to have only one table per worksheet, so the table always starts at top left and extends downards with no risk of running into another table

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't possible. This is an automated report that is received and to have to manually edit and separate out many many tables into their separate sheets/workbooks would be too much of a hassle.

Comment: are you open to using VBA to solve this?

Comment: Is VBA able to run as a script while no one is logged on? If that's the case then I am open to it. The entire point of this project was to receive the report, auto format it, then send it back out to the respective parties

Comment: Are you able to use the blank row as a delimiter between one table and the next? You mention it above, but it's not 100% clear. If so, you can find the title, get all rows up to the next blank row. For columns you can select all the columns in the row below the title, that are not None (e.g have a column title). Then you have a row range and a column range and you are good to go.

Comment: Yes, I could use the blank row as a delimiter between one table and the next, move down a row after find a title, then get all rows up to next blank row. I just don't know how to represent what I am asking into openpyxl/python. This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For selecting the cells you want, try something like this

```
def find_table(sheet, title):
    title_row = None
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        if row[0].value == title:
            # Find the title row
            title_row = row[0].row
        if row[0].value is None and title_row:
            end_row = row[0].row - 1
            break
    else:
        # The last row in the sheet
        end_row = row[0].row
return title_row, end_row
```

You can find the specific number of columns, for the given table with;

```
num_cols = len([cell.value for cell in sheet[title_row+1] if cell.value is not None])
```

That should give you the start and end rows, and the number of columns. You can then select those cells and use them to "make a table" in whatever form that takes for your specific example.

If you want to select a range of cells using Excels 'A1' style notation, you can always use `openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(idx)` to translate a numeric column number into the corresponding letter.

This solution is quite simplistic, and makes some assumptions about the format of your excel sheets, such as that the data always starts in ColumnA, that an empty cell in ColumnA indicates a totally empty row, and that the heading row always follows the title row. You would also probably want to add some error handling - for example, what if the title row is not found?
Hopefully this can give you a start in the right direction though, and some ideas to try out.

Comment: This is exactly what I was aiming for. As long as I can find the range then I'd be able to progress. Like they always say hindsight 20/20 because it is so simple I can't believe I didn't think of it. Thank you so much!

Comment: After running the code, it outputs like my edit above. The title row is correct, end row is showing the last row of the entire sheet which is incorrect and num_cols is showing the column headers instead of just a number for the last col in the table.

Comment: OK sure. See my edited answer above. It was my mistake, I wrote this from my head and didn't actually test it! You need a `break` in the for loop, so you don't iterate all the way to the other end of the sheet. As for `num_cols`, well we were finding the list of column names, so all you need to do is take `len()` of that. See if that helps.

Comment: You did pretty well from off your head without testing! That edit solved the issue, the function now gives the proper start row(title), end row(row before blank cell/row), and max column for that range